# Understand Verse 2:7 of Quran

Tags: tafseer, quran-translation, verses

The literal translation of the verse https://quran.com/2/7 is

> Allah has sealed their hearts, locking inside them their falsehood,
> and has placed a seal on their hearing, so that they do not listen to
> nor accept the truth. He has put a cover over their eyes so that they
> do not see the truth in its clarity. They will suffer greatly.

To whom does this verse refer? A non-Muslim disbeliever or a Muslim disbeliever?

If this verse refers to a non-Muslim disbeliever then doesn't this feel unjust? Why will Allah SWT punish someone for not believing and following Islam if He himself made them so? It's like they were stopped from not understanding and following Islam by Allah SWT himself and then in the afterlife, they are being punished for not following Islam.

If this verse refers to a Muslim disbeliever, then this should mean that any Muslim disbeliever shouldn't be able to revert back to Islam as Allah would have sealed his/her heart but there are instances where people have reverted back.

Please help me understand this verse.

Answer (score 0):

The freedom to believe or not believe is given to all.

> And say, "The truth is from your Lord, **so whoever wills - let him
> believe; and whoever wills - let him disbelieve.**" [Quran 18:29](https://quran.com/18/29)

The verse you quote is about the person who choose to disbelieve, in that case his heart and hearing will be sealed and his sight will be covered, so he sense the external world in such a way that it will justify his disbelief. There is nothing that stops him from believing, in that case these verses do not apply to him any more.

The decision to believe or not is based on whether he wants to be grateful or ungrateful

> We already showed them the Way, **whether they ˹choose to˺ be grateful
> or ungrateful.** [Quran 76:3](https://quran.com/en/al-insan/3)

So once a person believes in Allah, then Allah will guide him/her

> No disaster strikes except by permission of Allāh. **And whoever
> believes in Allāh - He will guide his heart.** And Allāh is Knowing of
> all things. [Quran 64:11](https://quran.com/at-taghabun/11)